# Referncing a range inside a VBA For loop

Tags: excel, vba

thank you for the help in advance!

I am creating a macro that writes to a text file. I am having trouble referencing a range inside of a for loop. There are two examples I have where the range I have called returns a "". For the first image below, this is where the user inputs data using a combination of entering data into the sheet and using a button that directs them to a user form that plops in what they entered. In this first image, where the user is directed by the userform, the data is outputted to another sheet and I use vlookup to display the info. I do this to run operations on the other sheet and just to help me keep track of everything, (novice vba user). The second sheet is where data is stored and calculations are run.

[1st image, User input and display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1f1W.png) [2nd image, data storage and calculation sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mumVF.png)

newDimName only outputs "_Cav" and the value stored in cavNum for the loop. The intention is concatenate the string inside of column A with more information depending on what the user has inputted. I suspect I am not referencing the range for column a correctly. The Loop is set to go to 2 to whatever amount of "dimensions" have been entered by the user (value in lastUserDim). The code below is contained with a sheet reference (not in the snippet) so it references the correct sheet. Ex. "With Sheet2", at before the loop and a "End With" at the end of the loop.

```
   Dim a As Integer, cavNum As Integer
Select Case numCav
    Case Is = 4
    For a = 2 To lastUserDim
            For cavNum = 1 To 4
                newDimName = Cells(a, 1) & "_Cav" & cavNum
            Next cavNum
    Next a
    totalColumns = 4 * lastUserDim
    Case Is = 8
    For a = 2 To lastUserDim
            For cavNum = 1 To 8
                newDimName = Cells(a, 1) & "_Cav" & cavNum
            Next cavNum
    Next a
    totalColumns = 8 * lastUserDim
    Case Is = 16
    For a = 2 To lastUserDim
            For cavNum = 1 To 16
                newDimName = Cells(a, 1) & "_Cav" & cavNum
            Next cavNum
    Next a
    totalColumns = 16 * lastUserDim
    Case Is = 32
    For a = 2 To lastUserDim
            For cavNum = 1 To 32
                newDimName = Cells(a, 1) & "_Cav" & cavNum
            Next cavNum
    Next a
    totalColumns = 32 * lastUserDim
    Case Else
    MsgBox "Please select what # of cavities this tool has."
End Select
```

For the code below, I want the the range I defined to be read and for the select case to determine if a cell contains yes or no. The loop is intended to run this operation for number of user inputted data. Again I suspect I am not calling the data in column c correctly like I was previously with Column A. I tried using cells like in the first code snippet, just range, range("").value, and range("").text.

```
Dim LSLBound As String, LSLBoundRef As String
Dim c As Integer
For c = 2 To lastUserDim
    LSLBoundRef = Range("C2:C" & c).Text 'ref to cell value to use for select case
Select Case LSLBoundRef
    Case Is = "No"
        LSLBound = "LBound 1;"
    Case Is = "Yes"
        'Do Nothing
        End Select
Next c
```

Comment: You need the range in `LSLBoundRef` to be a cell, not a multi-cell range.  After `2`, the range cannot equal `Yes` or `No`.  Try `Cells(c, 3)` and you will be comparing the cell value for each iteration.  And yes, you should reference the sheet.

Comment: My opposition to use `Cells(c, 3)` is that in the first code snippet when I used `Cells(a, 1)` it returned a null (empty) value. Even with the correct sheet reference for the code.

Comment: If you are not working with consistent data, you can test the cell prior to evaluating with `If not IsNull` or `If not IsEmpty` or `IsNumeric`.  Also, depending on how many items you expect, you would want to declare as `Long` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: In the example images above, using `Cells(a, 1)` or `Cells(c, 3)` should return values because the cells in the sheets have data inside them. Why is the cells function returning null value? In the second code snippet the Select Case doesnt run because there is no value to examine case and in the first code snipper the concatenation only returns "_Cav" and the value in cavNum

Comment: Perhaps this will help...https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/

Comment: @DarrellH reading this made me realize that I may be storing my outputs incorrectly. Should I be storing the outputs of these loops as a variant? That way, I can store the outputs in a column lets say and see all the concatenations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second code snippet is wrapped in a "With Sheet2", you need to preface the Range with a period, ie **.**Range("C2")... so that it is using the correct sheet.

```
Dim LSLBound As String, LSLBoundRef As String
Dim c As Integer
With Sheets("Sheet2")
For c = 2 To lastUserDim
    LSLBoundRef = .Range("C2:C" & c).Text 'ref to cell value to use for select case
    Select Case LSLBoundRef
        Case Is = "No"
            LSLBound = "LBound 1;"
        Case Is = "Yes"
            'Do Nothing
        End Select
 Next c
 End With
```

A good way to figure out what range is actually being referenced is by printing the range address to the immediate window with Debug.Print Range.Address.

Comment: By adding the "." before the Range call, I was able to pull a value from the cell correctly. But after running this on my first code snippet I get a data type mismatch after my For loop has run once completely through.

Comment: What line gives an error exactly? Type mismatch means you have declared a variable as one type but are assigning it a value of another type.